# Java: is there a difference in order when comparing strings?

Tags: java, string, comparison

I notice some people seem to differ when comparing two strings together, such as when comparing a variable to a constant. For example, let's say we have a constant string and an input method:

```
public final String CONSTANT_STRING = "A constant string";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Is it better or faster in any way to use the unknown input first:

```
br.readLine().equals(CONSTANT_STRING)
```

or to compare the constant to the unknown:

```
CONSTANT_STRING.equals(br.readLine());
```

Comment: Using the second option is called a [Yoda condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its not a matter of performance. The second version won't ever produce a `NullPointerException`, even when `br.readLine()` returns `null`. The first one does though.

Answer (score 3):

It's not better or faster, but if you *know* that `CONSTANT_STRING` exists you guarantee that you'll never get a `NullPointerException` if you do it the second way.

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` method of `String` class will return `false` if the length of two comparing strings are different. It will compare the contents only when the length of two strings are equal. So the order does not affect the performance.

As you can see in other answers, second method will not occur `NullPointerException`. So, the second method is better.

Answer (score 1):

public **abstract?** String CONSTANT_STRING = "A constant string";

Comment: whoops, I'll fix that quick.